# Упражнения на тему из Шилдта "Подробнее о методах и классах"

Tags: c#

Читаю сейчас главу в Шилдте. Полное руководство C# "Подробнее о методах и классах". Хочу на практике закрепить теорию из данной главы. Подкиньте или помогите найти упражнения для данного материала. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Да любая тема из жизни. Например, выборы ;)

Так и вижу интерфейс

```
interface Выборы {
    void голосовать(string паспорт, Партия партия);
    void фальсифицировать(Партия партия, int количество);
}
```